# C#: How to translate the Yield Keyword

Tags: c#, yield

1. What would the MSDN sample look like without the **yield** keyword? You may use any example if you perfer. I would just like to understand what is going on under the hood.
2. Is the **yield** operator **eagerly** or **lazily** evaluated?

**Sample:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
public class List
{
    public static IEnumerable Power(int number, int exponent)
    {
        int counter = 0;
        int result = 1;
        while (counter++ < exponent)
        {
            result = result * number;
            yield return result;
        }
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        // Display powers of 2 up to the exponent 8:
        foreach (int i in Power(2, 8))
        {
            Console.Write("{0} ", i);
        }
    }
}
```

- [MSDN - Yield Keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en/library/9k7k7cf0%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

---

If the yield operator is eagerly evaluated here is my guess:

```
    public static IEnumerable Power(int number, int exponent)
    {
        int counter = 0;
        int result = 1;
        List<int> powers;
        while (counter++ < exponent)
        {
            result = result * number;
            powers.add(result);
        }
        return powers;
    }
```

I have no clue what it might look like if the yield operator is lazily evaluated.

**Update:** Reflector gives this:

```
public class List
{
    // Methods
    public List();
    private static void Main();
    public static IEnumerable Power(int number, int exponent);

    // Nested Types
    [CompilerGenerated]
    private sealed class <Power>d__0 : IEnumerable<object>, IEnumerable, IEnumerator<object>, IEnumerator, IDisposable
    {
        // Fields
        private int <>1__state;
        private object <>2__current;
        public int <>3__exponent;
        public int <>3__number;
        private int <>l__initialThreadId;
        public int <counter>5__1;
        public int <result>5__2;
        public int exponent;
        public int number;

        // Methods
        [DebuggerHidden]
        public <Power>d__0(int <>1__state);
        private bool MoveNext();
        [DebuggerHidden]
        IEnumerator<object> IEnumerable<object>.GetEnumerator();
        [DebuggerHidden]
        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator();
        [DebuggerHidden]
        void IEnumerator.Reset();
        void IDisposable.Dispose();

        // Properties
        object IEnumerator<object>.Current { [DebuggerHidden] get; }
        object IEnumerator.Current { [DebuggerHidden] get; }
    }
}

IEnumerator<object> IEnumerable<object>.GetEnumerator()
{
    List.<Power>d__0 d__;
    if ((Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId == this.<>l__initialThreadId) && (this.<>1__state == -2))
    {
        this.<>1__state = 0;
        d__ = this;
    }
    else
    {
        d__ = new List.<Power>d__0(0);
    }
    d__.number = this.<>3__number;
    d__.exponent = this.<>3__exponent;
    return d__;
}



private bool MoveNext()
{
    switch (this.<>1__state)
    {
        case 0:
            this.<>1__state = -1;
            this.<counter>5__1 = 0;
            this.<result>5__2 = 1;
            while (this.<counter>5__1++ < this.exponent)
            {
                this.<result>5__2 *= this.number;
                this.<>2__current = this.<result>5__2;
                this.<>1__state = 1;
                return true;
            Label_0065:
                this.<>1__state = -1;
            }
            break;

        case 1:
            goto Label_0065;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/742497/yield-statement-implementation

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Back in the good old days, before we had the yield operator, we used to write classes which implemented IEnumerator.

```
class PowerEnumerator : IEnumerator<int>
{
  private int _number;
  private int _exponent;
  private int _current = 1;

  public PowerEnumerator(int number, int exponent)
  {
    _number = number;
    _exponent = exponent;
  }

  public bool MoveNext()
  {
    _current *= number;
    return _exponent-- > 0;
  }

  public int Current
  {
    get
    {
      if (_exponent < 0) throw new InvalidOperationException();
      return _current;
    }
  }
}
```

Or something like that. It wasn't fun, let me tell you.

Comment: Obviously I've implemented the generic version, although that wasn't available either. And we had to walk 5 miles in the snow just to start a build. Mind you, you could have a night out for £3.50 and still have enough change for a bag of chips and a bus home.

Comment: Amen. If I never again have to build an entire class just to have a strongly typed version of ArrayList, that's fine by me.

Comment: I appreciate Eric Lipperts answer but this answer hits the nail on the head.

Answer (score 11):

First off, yield is not an *operator*. yield return and yield break are *statements*.

There are plenty of articles available on how the compiler implements iterator blocks. Start by **reading the C# specification** section on iterator blocks; it gives some suggestions for how an implementer of C# might want to go about it.

Next read Raymond Chen's series "The implementation of iterators in C# and its consequences"

http://www.bing.com/search?q=raymond+chen+the+implementation+of+iterators

Next, read Jon Skeet's book chapter on the subject:

http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter6/IteratorBlockImplementation.aspx

If after all that you are *still* interested then read my series on the design factors that went into this feature:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/tags/iterators/

Comment: Thanks Eric, lots to read there. It's an intriguing statement (not operator lol).

Answer (score 0):

1. It would be a custom implementation of `IEnumerable<T>`, not leaning on an existing implementation such as `List<T>`
2. Lazily.

More info available [here](http://en.csharp-online.net/CSharp_Coding_Solutions%E2%80%94What_Does_Yield_Keyword_Generate).

Answer (score 0):

1. Let [.NET Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/) decompile it. It's a generic solution (a state machine actually), but quite complex, > 20 lines of codes if I remember correctly.
2. Lazy. That's the point why `yield` can be quite efficient.