# Yield statement's effect on program flow

Tags: c#, yield-return

I'm trying to understand the use of the yield keyword in C#, as a queue modelling package I'm using makes extensive use of it.

To demonstrate the use of yield, I am playing around with the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
public class YieldTest
{
    static void Main()
    {
        foreach (int value in ComputePower(2, 5))
        {
            Console.Write(value);
            Console.Write(" ");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
    /**
     * Returns an IEnumerable iterator of ints
     * suitable for use in a foreach statement
     */
    public static IEnumerable<int> ComputePower(int number, int exponent)
    {
        Console.Write ("Arguments to ComputePower are number: " + number + " exponent: " + exponent + "\n");
        int exponentNum = 0;
        int numberResult = 1;
        while (exponentNum < exponent)
        {
            numberResult *= number;
            exponentNum++;
            // yield: 
            // a) returns back to the calling function (foreach),
            // b) updates iterator value (2,4,8,16,32 etc.)
            yield return numberResult;
        }
    }
}
```

It's pretty evident what the code does, it simply raises 2 to a power using `ComputePower` which returns an `IEnumerable`. In debugging the code, I see the `yield` statement return control to the `foreach` loop, and the `value` variable is updated with the latest result of the power ie. 2, 4, 8, 16, 32.

Not fully understanding the use of `yield`, I expected `ComputePower` to be called a number of times as value iterates through `ComputePower` and that I would see the `"Arguments to ComputePower are "` etc. console write occur 5 times. What actually happens though is it seems the `ComputePower` method is called only once. I see the `"Arguments to ComputePower.."` string only once per run.

Can somebody explain why this is the case? Does it have something to do with the `yield` keyword?

Comment: Have you read [yield](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx)?

Comment: You should be able to step through it in the debugger to see the exact flow.

Comment: Yeah, or Jon Skeet's _C# in Depth_ explains this very nicely

Comment: possible duplicate of [yield statement implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/742497/yield-statement-implementation)

Comment: Also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4683153/119477) gives links to some of the best resources on the subject

Comment: Decompile your sample with ILSpy, having `Decompile enumerator (yield return)` option turned off.

Comment: Thanks for the references, I also found this one which is pretty good: http://visualstudiomagazine.com/Articles/2012/02/01/Demystifying-the-C-Yield-Return-Mechanism.aspx?Page=1 It looks like a pretty powerful keyword, I'm going to try to understand it fully as it looks as if it can gracefully solve lots of iterating problems like processing record-type based flat files etc.

Comment: LOL that's what initiated the question in the first place, the stepping through and seeing a 'jump' I wasn't expecting, but as Marius explained, that's the whole point.

Comment: Brief answer to the specific question, thanks to the guidance in the responses: ComputePower (more specifically, part of it ie. the non iterating loop section) is 'called' only once. The use of yield makes a kind of placeholder, to which control returns as the IEnumerable iterator moves through the value variable. This section of the code is called multiple times. The 3 lines of initial code is only called once. The 5 answers all provide excellent information on how yield works, hope they're useful to other stackoverflow people!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The foreach will iterate the IEnumerable returned from ComputePower. "Yield return" automatically creates an implementation of IEnumerable so you don't have to hand-roll it. If you put a breakpoint inside your "while"-loop you will see it getting called for each iteration

From msdn:

> You consume an iterator method by using a foreach statement or LINQ query. Each iteration of the foreach loop calls the iterator method. When a yield return statement is reached in the iterator method, expression is returned, and the current location in code is retained. Execution is restarted from that location the next time that the iterator function is called.

Comment: The key part there being "Execution is restarted from that location the next time that the iterator function is called".

Comment: I think JohnDRoadch is right to the point. I learned this from python's help on yield, and think they share similar concept.

Comment: Thanks Marius, good explanation, and JohnDRoach I think your emphasis answers the question I was asking - 'execution is restarted...' is absolutely key to understanding the use of yield. Thanks again guys.

Answer (score 2):

`yield return` causes the compiler to build a state machine which implements `IEnumerable<T>` using the body of your method. It returns an object from your method without actually invoking the body of your method as you wrote it - the compiler has replaced it with something more complex.

When you call `MoveNext()` on the `IEnumerator<T>` produced by the state machine (such as during a `foreach` loop), the state machine executes your method code until it reaches the first `yield return` statement. It then sets the value of `Current` to whatever value you returned and then yields control back to the caller.

In practise, it looks as though your method body is executed once per iteration and the loop is "interrupted" each time you reach a `yield return` statement.

If you put a breakpoint in your method's while loop, you will see the stack contains a call to `MoveNext()` on the compiler-generated type which your method's body has become part of.

Comment: Thanks Tragedian. That's the nub of the matter: the appearance of the method body executed only once per iteration. Good explanation.

Answer (score 1):

On a high level, you can think of `yield` as saying 'return a value and freeze the current state of the method. When the generator is next called, the method will thaw and resume starting at the line following the yield'. So any line that is only at the start of the method and not actually in the loop where `yield` exists will only be called once, it doesn't start the whole method over again.

On a low level, `yield` is implemented by the compiler transforming your method into a state machine, where a jump table is added at the start of the method and which jump we take (which yield line of code we start executing at when you call the method) is determined by the 'state' the generator was last in. A similar coding technique is used for await/async state machines, and allows a lot of complexity to be hidden from the programmer under an easier to understand model.

Comment: Thanks Patashu, the implementation of yield seems pretty sophisticated, and as you say hides alot of complexity.

Answer (score 0):

The yield operator will force compiler to create a custom class which will implement your logic.
The better way to understand it is decompile result exe and watch into it.