# Why does this code using yield return compile?

Tags: c#, ienumerable

As you might expect, this code produces a compiler error:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> Foo()
{
}
```

> not all code paths return a value

However, this compiles with only a warning about unreachable code:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> Foo()
{
    if(false)
    {
        yield return 0;
    }
}
```

This produces an empty enumerable. Why does this work, and is it defined behavior?

Comment: Wow, I give the c# compiler a lot of credit if this is actually the case. @mjwills

Comment: @JamieTaylorSangerman It is almost the other way around. The compiler is quite stupid - it just says 'well, I see a yield return' by my understanding. It doesn't try and do excessive reachability analysis etc etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
public static IEnumerable<int> Foo()
{
}
```

The first has no return (hence the compiler message). Which makes sense - it doesn't have enough context to know what to do. *Should it return `null`? An empty enumerable? It can't know - so it won't let you compile.*

```
public static IEnumerable<int> Foo()
{
    if(false)
    {
        yield return 0;
    }
}
```

The second does have a `yield return` (even if unreachable), which gives it enough context to know that you **want** to return an enumerable (so it can set up the necessary state machine). Now, when the code executes you never actually hit that `yield return` line (hence the compiler warning) - so what the caller will get is an empty enumerable.
This is [expected](https://stackoverflow.com/a/742501/34092) -

> If you don't have a yield break, the compiler would assume one at the
>   end of the function (just like a return; statement in a normal
>   function)

Given how ugly and un-intuitive the second code sample is, you may wish to instead use:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> Foo()
{
    yield break;
}
```

Since it compiles, is clearer in its intent, and the compiler won't complain about unreachable code.

Comment: In my real code, the condition tested a variable. I looked at what I'd just written and wondered why I wasn't getting a compiler error. Interesting gotcha.