# Cannot yield even though the return type is IEnumerable<U>

Tags: c#, generics

Consider the following trivial example:

```
class Filter<T, U>
    where T : IEnumerable<U>
    where U : IEquatable<U>
{
    private readonly U id;

    public Filter(U id) => this.id = id;

    public T Eval_A(T items)
    {
        foreach (var item in items)
            if (item.Equals(id))
                yield return item;
    }

    public IEnumerable<U> Eval_B(IEnumerable<U> items)
    {
        foreach (var item in items)
            if (item.Equals(id))
                yield return item;
    }
}
```

Even though `T` is of type `IEnumerable<U>`, an error still occurs for `T Eval_A(T items)` as follows.

> The body of 'accessor' cannot be an iterator block because 'type' is not an iterator interface type

MSDN said:

> This error occurs if an iterator accessor is used but the return type is not one of the iterator interface types: `IEnumerable`, `IEnumerable<T>`, `IEnumerator`, `IEnumerator<T>`. To avoid this error, use one of the iterator interface types as a return type.

I think the return type does conforms to the requirement.

What am I missing here?

Comment: The return type has to be *exactly* one of those types, not `T`.

Comment: No `T` is something that implements `IEnumerable<U>`. Your class allows `Filter<List<U>, U>` which can't be an iterator.

Comment: The problem here is that T can also be a type **derived** from _IEnumerable<T>_. However, iterator methods do not allow return types that are derivatives of _IEnumerable / IEnumerable<T> / IEnumerator / IEnumerator<T>_. Hence the error. For example, you cannot create an iterator method with a return type of List<T>, despite List<T> being an IEnumerable<T>.

Comment: When we put `yield return` .net compiles it into a finite state machine which provides `IEnumerable<U>` as a return; but here we want an *additional cast* in order to return `T`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return type of the method has to be *exactly* one of `IEnumerable`, `IEnumerable<T>`, `IEnumerator` or `IEnumerator<T>`, and not `T`, which is some type that implements `IEnumerable<U>`.

This is because the way that iterator methods work, is that the compiler generates a type implementing one of the above interfaces, with the `MoveNext` and `Current` correctly implemented so that it matches the behaviour of your method, and then it rewrites your method to return an instance of that type instead.

For example, for:

```
public IEnumerable<int> GetSingleDigitNumbersLoop()
{
    int index = 0;
    while (index < 10)
        yield return index++;
}
```

The following is generated (seen using [SharpLab.io](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgZgpghgLgrgJwgZwLQGUawJYGMCCwyMCUuMAshALbAQLICSAdizPWGSgD4ACATAEYAsACheABgAEvQQBYA3GN4BmGfykBhKQG9la2SoA82ZjAB8UgOIQY6UwHMANhAAi2B9hgA5OLXrIADIA9sEADgAUAJRieqJSCVKmMEnMACYQAB5SALxSEkrxiQDuABbYLlIRphnZRlKCEjFFiYmygjIA7Km1ANS9hQC+YoNAA)):

```
[IteratorStateMachine(typeof(<GetSingleDigitNumbersLoop>d__0))]
public IEnumerable<int> GetSingleDigitNumbersLoop()
{
    return new <GetSingleDigitNumbersLoop>d__0(-2);
}

[CompilerGenerated]
private sealed class <GetSingleDigitNumbersLoop>d__0 : IEnumerable<int>, IEnumerable, IEnumerator<int>, IDisposable, IEnumerator
{
    private int <>1__state;

    private int <>2__current;

    private int <>l__initialThreadId;

    private int <index>5__2;

    int IEnumerator<int>.Current
    {
        [DebuggerHidden]
        get
        {
            return <>2__current;
        }
    }

    object IEnumerator.Current
    {
        [DebuggerHidden]
        get
        {
            return <>2__current;
        }
    }

    [DebuggerHidden]
    public <GetSingleDigitNumbersLoop>d__0(int <>1__state)
    {
        this.<>1__state = <>1__state;
        <>l__initialThreadId = Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId;
    }

    [DebuggerHidden]
    void IDisposable.Dispose()
    {
    }

    private bool MoveNext()
    {
        int num = <>1__state;
        if (num != 0)
        {
            if (num != 1)
            {
                return false;
            }
            <>1__state = -1;
        }
        else
        {
            <>1__state = -1;
            <index>5__2 = 0;
        }
        if (<index>5__2 < 10)
        {
            <>2__current = <index>5__2++;
            <>1__state = 1;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    bool IEnumerator.MoveNext()
    {
        //ILSpy generated this explicit interface implementation from .override directive in MoveNext
        return this.MoveNext();
    }

    [DebuggerHidden]
    void IEnumerator.Reset()
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    [DebuggerHidden]
    IEnumerator<int> IEnumerable<int>.GetEnumerator()
    {
        if (<>1__state == -2 && <>l__initialThreadId == Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId)
        {
            <>1__state = 0;
            return this;
        }
        return new <GetSingleDigitNumbersLoop>d__0(0);
    }

    [DebuggerHidden]
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return ((IEnumerable<int>)this).GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

`<GetSingleDigitNumbersLoop>d__0` is the type that implements `IEnumerable<int>` that `GetSingleDigitNumbersLoop` is rewritten to return instead.

Now, if `GetSingleDigitNumbersLoop` were declared to return some other type, like a type parameter `T` for example, the following wouldn't work:

```
public T GetSingleDigitNumbersLoop()
{
    return new <GetSingleDigitNumbersLoop>d__0(-2);
}
```

Because `<GetSingleDigitNumbersLoop>d__0` is not necessarily a `T`. In fact it almost never would be, because it is a compiler generated type!

See also: [yield statement implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/742497/5133585)