# What's the defference between "yield break" and "break" in iterator blocks?

Tags: c#, linq

I've seen something in **Enumerable.cs** like this:

```
private static IEnumerable<TSource> TakeWhileIterator<TSource>(
  IEnumerable<TSource> source,
  Func<TSource, bool> predicate)
{
  foreach (TSource source1 in source)
  {
    if (predicate(source1))
      yield return source1;
    else
      break; // break
  }
}
```

So I write something like this:

```
private static IEnumerable<TSource> TakeWhileIteratorWithYield<TSource>(
  IEnumerable<TSource> source,
  Func<TSource, bool> predicate)
{
  foreach (TSource source1 in source)
  {
    if (predicate(source1))
      yield return source1;
    else
      yield break; // yield break
  }
}
```

I've tried these two methods and it seems like they have quite the same function.
So I go to [SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/) and decomplie these codes.
The main differences are in `MoveNext()` I think, like this:
**No Yield**

```
private bool MoveNext()
{
    try
    {
        switch (_state)
        {
            default:
                return false;
            case 0:
                _state = -1;
                _s__1 = source.GetEnumerator();
                _state = -3;
                break;
            case 1:
                _state = -3;
                _source5__2 = default(TSource);
                break;
        }

        // From Here
        if (_s__1.MoveNext())
        {
            _source5__2 = _s__1.Current;
            if (predicate(_source5__2))
            {
                _current = _source5__2;
                _state = 1;
                return true;
            }
        }

        Finally1();
        _s__1 = null;
        return false;
        // To Here
    }
    catch
    {
        //try-fault
        ((IDisposable) this).Dispose();
        throw;
    }
}
```

**Have Yield**

```
private bool MoveNext()
{
    try
    {
        switch (_state)
        {
            default:
                return false;
            case 0:
                _state = -1;
                _s__1 = source.GetEnumerator();
                _state = -3;
                break;
            case 1:
                _state = -3;
                _source5__2 = default(TSource);
                break;
        }

        // From Here
        if (!_s__1.MoveNext())
        {
            Finally1();
            _s__1 = null;
            return false;
        }

        _source5__2 = _s__1.Current;
        if (predicate(_source5__2))
        {
            _current = _source5__2;
            _state = 1;
            return true;
        }

        bool result = false;
        Finally1();
        return result;
        // To Here
    }
    catch
    {
        //try-fault
        ((IDisposable) this).Dispose();
        throw;
    }
}
```

I can't see the functional differences between them.
Could someone tell me the differences between `break` and `yield break` in iterator blocks?

Comment: and the comment on this answer of the dupe target may help https://stackoverflow.com/a/231945/6560478

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "yield break;" do in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231893/what-does-yield-break-do-in-c)

Comment: `yield break` ends the iteration, `break` ends the loop ect. You can imagine how this is different

Comment: @DragandDrop Thank you very much. I do seen that question but not the comment in the first answer. Good Day!