# Sonar issues with null check C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, sonarqube, microservices, visual-studio-2022

After enabling Sonar in my project I get the following message

> myEntities is null on at least one execution path.

```
public static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<MyDto,long>> PrepareClientResponses(this IEnumerable<MyServiceCnt> myEntities)
{
    if (myEntities == null || !myEntities.Any())
    {
        yield return default;
    }         
    foreach (var myEntities in myEntities)
    {
        var client = myEntities.PrepareClientResponse();
        yield return new KeyValuePair<MyDto, long>(client, myEntities.MyId.Value);
    }
}
```

The message is on the "myEntities" on the `foreach (var myEntities in myEntities)` line.

Can someone suggest me on how to solve this message. I am checking null condition but it still gives this warning.

Comment: `foreach (var myEntities in myEntities)` is wrong, you're using the very same variable! Shouldn't it be `foreach (var myEntity in myEntities)`?

Comment: @Marco `foreach (var myEntities in myEntities)` even *does not compile* since `myEntities` is also a parameter in the method.

Comment: Its actually a copy paste mistake from myend..rectified in my code @Mustafa

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `yield return default;`

`yield return` roughly means "give back a value and continue once the next value is requested".

So, the loop is executed even if the `yield return` is never reached.

For fixing this, you have multiple options.

#### `yield break`

Instead of the `yield return` in the `if`, you can use `yield break` in order to terminate the method as [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/231945/10871900).

```cs
public static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<MyDto,long>> PrepareClientResponses(this IEnumerable<MyServiceCnt> myEntities)
{
    if (myEntities == null || !myEntities.Any())
    {
        yield return default;
        yield break;
    }
    foreach (var e in myEntities)
    {
        var client = e.PrepareClientResponse();
        yield return new KeyValuePair<MyDto, long>(client, e.MyId.Value);
    }
    
}
```

#### `else`

You can just put the loop in an `else`-block. This way, it won't be executed in case the check evaluates to true:

```cs
public static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<MyDto,long>> PrepareClientResponses(this IEnumerable<MyServiceCnt> myEntities)
{
    if (myEntities == null || !myEntities.Any())
    {
        yield return default;
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (var e in myEntities)
        {
            var client = e.PrepareClientResponse();
            yield return new KeyValuePair<MyDto, long>(client, e.MyId.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

#### do nothing

In some cases, it might be a sensible decision to not return any element in case a preconception fails. But note that your code will behave differently if you arr doing that.

```cs
public static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<MyDto,long>> PrepareClientResponses(this IEnumerable<MyServiceCnt> myEntities)
{
    if (myEntities != null && myEntities.Any())
    {
        foreach (var e in myEntities)
        {
            var client = e.PrepareClientResponse();
            yield return new KeyValuePair<MyDto, long>(client, e.MyId.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

### other problem

Please see this [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75730260/10871900) by [@Marco](https://stackoverflow.com/users/604015/marco) for another problem with your code (which I also integrated in this answer).

Comment: Good answer, I miised one error :)

Comment: I would have also missed the problem you found.

Comment: Thanks , i have implemented the second case ie with "else " implementation and bug got resolved. Also have incorporated @Macros s point also to work.

Comment: @dan1st here  yield return default;
        yield break; yield break is only needed here? Should i have yield return as well as yield break

Comment: if you use `yiels return default` before `yield break`, you woukd get the value `default` when iterating over it. If you just use `yield break;`, it will be empty.

Answer (score 2):

You have an error in your foreach loop:
`foreach (var myEntities in myEntities)`

It is wrong because you're using the very same variable for the loop!
It should be:

```
foreach (var myEntity in myEntities)
{
    var client = myEntity.PrepareClientResponse();
    yield return new KeyValuePair<MyDto, long>(client, myEntity.MyId.Value);
}
```